# Usb not recognised in android studio

Tags: android, usb-drive

i have a ASUS zenfone4 ASUS_T00Q... and i am learner in android development. i could not make my phone recognised in android studio.please help .
I have tried updating my drivers and also tried installing Google USB driver.

Comment: make sure you enabled Developer mode in your phone

Comment: Have you install device and google ADB drivers?

Comment: try toggling to mass storage/usb storage in connected options?

Comment: @AndroidDev .... i have

Comment: @amy yes i have ... but its not working... my system is windows 8 ....

Answer (score 0):

this will most likely work for you.

Install [PDANet+](http://pdanet.co/a/) and Android Studio should be able to recognise your device.

Comment: did u install it on both your PC and phone?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, i tried toggling usb options from mtp to ptp and it worked